# Is it possible to load a launcher activity as bottom sheet

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

It is for a few days that I am looking for a solution for launching a new activity as bottom sheet, In fact I have an application in which I want to load a new activity as bottom sheet when user goes to a new location, 
Here my problem is:
How can I launch my activity as bottom sheet on top of other activities. For example user is listening to music on music player, I want to launch my activity as bottom sheet on top of music player, I can launch a normal activity but can I launch it as bottom sheet too?
I have found these links but none of them answers my questions

[BottomSheet every thing](http://www.hidroh.com/2016/06/17/bottom-sheet-everything/)
[this one](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031)

Comment: Use your activity as a _Dialog_ activity with applying dialog theme in manifest file or use [this](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

Comment: @Piyush but it does not seem to be any bottom sheet.right?what if I want to lunch my activity as main activity?